# I am Calculating Average RMSE Loss in Pytorch Neural Network regression model. Is it correct?

Tags: python, pytorch

```
train_losses=[]
val_losses=[]

for epoch in range(EPOCH):
  train_loss = 0
  valid_loss = 0

  # train steps
  net.train()
  for batch_index, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
    target = target.reshape(-1,1)

    # clears gradients
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    # forward pass
    output, dense2_output = net(data)
    eps = 1e-6
    #loss in batch
    loss = torch.sqrt(criterion(output, target.double())+eps)
    
    # backward pass for loss gradient
    loss.backward()
    
    # update paremeters/weights
    optimizer.step()
    
    # update training loss
    #train_loss += math.pow(loss.item(),2)*data.size(0)
    train_loss += loss.item()*data.size(0)


  # average loss calculations
  #train_loss = math.sqrt(train_loss/len(train_loader.sampler))
  train_loss = train_loss/len(train_loader.sampler)

  
  # Display loss statistics
  print(f'Current Epoch: {epoch}\n Training Loss: {round(train_loss, 6)}')

  train_losses.append(train_loss)
```

I am Calculating Average RMSE Loss in Pytorch Neural Network regression model. Is it the correct way ?
Please help me understand if there is any error with my approach.
Actually i want to know if there is any bug in my code

Comment: I guess the answer depends on what s inside your `criterion` variable